# Sort emails based by number of emails from that recipicant

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have an email account which I get about twelve billion emails a day.  Okay, maybe an exaggeration, but it is an an account which I share with my wife (I know, who does that now a days?) and it is a little overwhelming.

Every now and then when I get inspired, I go through emails starting with a given letter and delete the spam.

Is it possible to sort emails in outlook based on the number of emails I received from a given sender?  Then I can make some real progress!

Comment: You should sort by `Conversation` and add it with `Field Chooser` options if it's not there. Then you could delete all but the newest date and time wise and that'd give you the latest and greatest email per conversation. If your "progress" is based on space to get back, then find the largest folder, within it sort by size, delete the attachments after saving or confirming those are needed starting with the largest first. Move onto the next largest folder after that and repeat the process. I'm not certain you can sort by the number of emails per FROM address easily without code though at least.

Comment: @Walmart  "progress" is not really based on storage as that currently isn't an issue.  It is based on having a manageable number of emails to review.  I get lost with the numerous superfluous emails.  I will look into your recommendations, however, I currently do not know whether they are appropriate or note.  Thanks!

Comment: I just wanted to mention the thing about the largest folder and then the largest emails "size wise" since you could technically spend lots of time deleting 1000 emails that do NOT even equal the "size" of one large email so if space is of importance, that may be better than sorting by conversation. Otherwise, conversation would probably be the next best option based on the volume per conversation so you could delete all but the newest email per conversation per Outlook folder. I'll be glad to add as an answer if you wish or find helpful, just let me know.

Comment: I just click the column heading "from" in outlook, then select the first email, scrll down to the last email, Hold down the shift key and click the last email. Let up shift, right click and select delete, poof all emails from that sender are gone.

Comment: @Tyson I just press CTRL+A and then follow that up with a DELETE and poof-be-gone all those pesky and stressful emails. **Doctor's Note:**  *Deleting all your email everyday keeps the doctors away!!*

Answer (score 0):

The Xobni addin rates contacts based on numbers of emails sent and received. It creates indexes for smarter searching, which will let you view all emails from your number 1 contact etc. 
https://support.xobni.com/hc/en-us/articles/215189626-Download-Xobni-for-Outlook-Infinity-Edition